# How add common header and footer in html page for multi page website using Node js, ExpressJS,hbs or ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want create common **header(navbar)** and **footer** page to be included in **multipage/several page** of website.
Create dynamic Website using nodejs and expressjs

Putting code for navbar and footer in common **header.html** and **footer.html** and call or include this common header/navbar and footer html page in other html pages.

How to use templating engine like **hbs or ejs** for website creation using Nodejs and expressJs

I know that it can be do using php or jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>document</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">navbar</div>

<!--Remaining section-->

<div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**But not using the following way:**

**W3school  w3-include**

```
<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
    ''Page content''
    <?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: You could use a jspf to include in the page, but I guess you don't want to use that right.

Comment: you still can use frames / iframes. this is how it was done in pure html before dynamic backend languages. now the common approach is to compose the page on the server

Comment: @ Adassko Thank you for the answer and Suggestion But wanted  in Modern way of writing by using  pure javascript /ES6 . No server

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your html files like

- `header.html` contains only header code
- `footer.html` contains only footer code
- `content.html` contains something like:

  > #### Here Heading
  >
  > Content for page
- in your `.htaccess` file

  AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm

So it will parse all html files as PHP files and include and execute all php code.

In case of loading via js/jquery.

Your html should be

```
<header></header>
<div class="middle">page content here</div>
<footer></footer>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('header').load("header.html");
    $('footer').load("footer.html");


});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this !.  Would like to use HTML or plain javascript or using Node js only 
@Naveed Ramzan

Comment: @Sid I have updated code for JQuery too. Have a look and upvote if workable.

Answer (score 0):

You provided all (straightforward) solutions already. You can either use:

1. PHP, ASP.NET, JSP, etc. functionality at the server side, or
2. AJAX / XHR / Fetch API functionality in JavaScript at the client side.

As far as I know, there is no way to use something like "master pages" or "template pages" purely client-side (inside the browser) using just HTML and JavaScript. :-(

There used to be some functionality called [HTML imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) (as part of HTML web components), but it has been abandoned some time ago.

If there is a way to do what you want, I will be very happy to learn about it too. :-)

Comment: Thanks... for answer can be done using Node js with es6 or lastest version of ES